# Using a toggle to run a JS function that requires a json from a GET call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am struggling to use a toggle to convert my incoming Kelvin temperature to C and then to F. Currently it works to load the page as it defaults to Celsius, but when i toggle the function outside of locationLook runs and it doesnt have access to the temperature provided in the GET. Does anyone have a clue or resource that may help me with my dillema, i am trying to learn JS as someone new to programming. from what i can tell its a scope issue and the outer function doesnt have access to the json after its initial run.

http://codepen.io/CamMakoJ/pen/yemYyE?editors=1010

this is my HTML toggle button

F° C°

and this is my js function for switching from C to F based on the toggle:

```
    function factorClick(rawTemp) {
      if (document.getElementById("myCheck").checked == true) {
       //setup Celsius
       var temp = Math.round(rawTemp - 273.15);
       document.getElementById("temperature").innerHTML = temp + " °C";
       return rawTemp;
    } else {
     //setup farenheit
     var temp = Math.round((rawTemp - 273.15 * 1.8) + 32);
     document.getElementById("temperature").innerHTML = temp + " °F";
     return rawTemp;
    }
```

this is the function that GETS the json from the weather API and then updates the HTML:

```
    function locationLook(latitude, longitude) {
  var json = $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "&appid=000000000000000000000000000", function(json) {
    console.log(json)
    var ktemp = json.main.temp
    factorClick(ktemp)
    icons(json)
    document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = json.weather[0].main;
    document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = json.name + ", " + json.sys.country;

  });
}
```

Comment: this is the toggle button

<div class="togglebutton">
  <label>
    <input onclick='factorClick()' id="myCheck" type="checkbox" checked="true">F°<span class="toggle"></span> C°
  </label>
</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue**

Initially you are passing `ktemp` as an argument to `factorClick` -

```
var ktemp = json.main.temp
factorClick(ktemp)
```

On click, `factorClick` is not passed the `ktemp` argument -

```
<input onclick='factorClick()' id="myCheck" type="checkbox" checked="true">F°<span class="toggle"
```

As such, when the input is clicked, the `rawTemp` argument in `factorClick` is undefined -

```
function factorClick(rawTemp) {

  if (document.getElementById("myCheck").checked == true) {
    //setup Celsius
    var temp = Math.round(rawTemp - 273.15);

  ...
}
```

Because operations with `undefined` return `NaN`, `temp` is not a number.

**Solution**

You are correct in that this is any issue of scope. Variable `ktemp` is currently locally scoped to the `locationLook` function. By defining `ktemp` in the global scope, `ktemp` can be referenced from within the scope of `factorClick`.

For example -

```
var ktemp;

//Location functions (gets run in geoSuccess)
function locationLook(latitude, longitude) {
  var json = $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "&appid=0426deb1eeda2f667e8c4f40675474fe", function(json) {
    console.log(json)
    ktemp = json.main.temp
    factorClick()
    icons(json)
    document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = json.weather[0].main;
    document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = json.name + ", " + json.sys.country;

  });
}

...

function factorClick() {

  if (document.getElementById("myCheck").checked == true) {

    // Use global ktemp variable
    var temp = Math.round(ktemp - 273.15);

    document.getElementById("temperature").innerHTML = temp + " °C";
    return ktemp;
  } else {
    //setup farenheit
    var temp = Math.round((ktemp - 273.15 * 1.8) + 32);
    document.getElementById("temperature").innerHTML = temp + " °F";
    return ktemp;
  }
}
```

See [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript) for more information.

Comment: Took me a while to get back to it, but awesome thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You should store temperature outside of function at first. When your app starts getWeather() function is called and after it gets data from server you can set temperature in your weather object.

```
var weather = {};

function getWeather(position) {
     weather.temperature = 40; // data from api.openweathermap.org 
}

getWeather(myPosition)
```

And then make function which is called on click on toggle. And you can access temperature from your object -> (weather.temperature). Something like this:

```
toggle.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (document.getElementById("myCheck").checked == true) {
        document.getElementById("temerature").innerHTML = Math.round(weather.temperature - 273.15) + " °C";

    } else {
        document.getElementById("temerature").innerHTML = Math.round((wether.temerature - 273.15 * 1.8) + 32) + " °F";
    }
}, false)
```